# Site-To-Site VPN between different Azure sites?

Tags: azure

I need to establish a VPN connection between 2 different Azure DC in EU and APAC. Is there a way to do it or not? I'd like a direct connection without passing through an on-premise DC.

I read and studied everything, but I haven't found a solution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently a VPN connection between 2 Windows Azure datacenters without using an on-premises location is not supported.

Comment: so the only possible way is using an on-premise DC as "bridge" :( Bad news. This is a real limitation. I hope Microsoft will fix this soon, because it's a must for a good distributed architecture in the cloud.